# Rails: Tawk.to chat plugin and Turbolinks issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chat, turbolinks, tawk.to

Hi I want to integrate the chat plugin Tawk.to into my rails app, however adding the script as they give it won't work with Turbolinks, I also tried to add the script into a function and call it on .ready and on page:load however it is not working, this is the original script:

```
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
  (function(){
  var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s1.async=true;
  s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/API_KEY/default';
  s1.charset='UTF-8';
  s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
  })();
```

I tried the following in my application.js file:

```
function tawk_chat(){
    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
    var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async=true;
    s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/API_KEY/default';
    s1.charset='UTF-8';
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
}

$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
  tawk_chat();
});
```

The above did not work. How to make work the above script with Turbolinks enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Ruby gem called [Tawk-rails](https://github.com/luizpicolo/tawk-rails), however I installed and tested it and it has the same issue of Turbolinks, so I started to try to fix this issue.

Actually fix Tawk script for make it work with Turbolinks is very easy, you just need to set the `$_Tawk` variable as undefined, so the resultant script would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript”>
window.$_Tawk = undefined; 
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/#{Tawk_account_id}/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8’;
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*’);
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
```

You can add the above script directly in your application.js into a function and then call it on .ready or you can install [this](https://github.com/ssoulless/tawk-rails/tree/turbolinks_compatibility) forked version of the Tawk-rails gem where I fix this issue

I already did a pull request to the original gem, so once they merge it I will update the answer.

## Update

Now the pull request is merged in to the original gem, now you can install tawk-rails gem, and Tawk.to will work as expected even with Turbolinks enabled

Comment: I think i have add `window.$_Tawk = undefined;` line into the init script, and it work in first few page visit, but after that, it doesn't work again!

Comment: Thanks! Its very helpful. But can you explain what is happening with that variable?

Comment: well it looks that `$_Tawk` variable was initialized somewhere else, causing the script to fail

Comment: If you are using Turbolinks **remember to put the script inside the HTML body tag.**